# Where to store the state in MVC model

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm writing an infinite scrolling list. There is a data grid that displays the data and a controller and model that provides the data to this grid.

Right now, the view receives the list of data and displays it. For the sake of infinite scrolling, it throws an event which lets its parent know that it needs the next page of data. The parent requests the next page of data, and it's the controller that decides what is the next page of data (in terms of page number, page size, etc.)

I'd like to know where I should keep the page number and page size, or in general, using MVC, where are we supposed to keep the state ?

Comment: In the controller. View is for representation, model for 'static' data, the controller for stateful data

Comment: Is this based on personal experience or is it a widely known best practice ?